# incompatible shapes with model.fit

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, google-colaboratory, training-data

I'm running into an incompatible shapes error that I am not able to trace. I'm trying to use the code provided here: https://data-flair.training/blogs/face-mask-detection-with-python/ and I'm working on google colab. I'm at step 5 where I train the model with model.fit_generator() which is where the [10,2] vs [10,3] error happens, Using fit() gets the same error.

As far as I can tell the [10,2] comes from the model that I'm using where I set the model's shape with the last Dense layer, but I'm not sure where the [10,3] is coming from, I have a feeling it is with the train_datagen or train_generator, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Here's my current code, I've made a few changes but the error is the same as the one I get using the provided code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import cv2
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Input, ZeroPadding2D, BatchNormalization, Activation, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense,Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard, ModelCheckpoint
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
import imutils
import numpy as np

#Conv and MaxPool layers extract features from dataset,
#Flatten and Dropout layers convert data in 1d and ensure overfitting
#2 dense layers for classification

#groups a linear stack of layers into a tf.keras.Model
#Conv2D: 2d convulation layer(spatial convolution over images)
#provide keyword argument input_shape

model = Sequential([ #
    Conv2D(100, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)),
    #input_shape of photos will be (150,150), color photos so 3 channels
    MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    
    Conv2D(100, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    
    Flatten(), #flattens data into a single array
    Dropout(0.5), #randomly sets '0.5' of inputs to 0
    Dense(50, activation='relu'), # model outputs arrays of shape(none,50)
    Dense(2, activation='softmax') # model outputs arrays of shape(none,2)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
#print(model.summary())
#print(model.output_shape)

TRAINING_DIR = "./train"
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255,
                                   rotation_range=40,
                                   width_shift_range=0.2,
                                   height_shift_range=0.2,
                                   shear_range=0.2,
                                   zoom_range=0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip=True,
                                   fill_mode='nearest')
#print(train_datagen.data_format)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(TRAINING_DIR, 
                                                    batch_size=10, 
                                                    target_size=(150, 150))

#print(train_generator.image_shape)
VALIDATION_DIR = "./test"
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255)

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(VALIDATION_DIR, 
                                                         batch_size=10, 
                                                         target_size=(150, 150))

#callback checkpoint, saves best model after each epoch while training
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('model2-{epoch:02d}.model',
                             monitor='val_loss',
                             verbose=1,
                             save_best_only=True,
                             mode='auto')
#print(checkpoint.model.output_shape())

print()
#print(checkpoint.shape())
#train model here, with fit_generator
history = model.fit(train_generator,
                    epochs=10,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

Here is the error.

```
Found 1315 images belonging to 3 classes.
Found 194 images belonging to 3 classes.

Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-06d6f3664a3f> in <module>()
     74                     epochs=10,
     75                     validation_data=validation_generator,
---> 76                     callbacks=[checkpoint])

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [10,3] vs. [10,2]
     [[node binary_crossentropy/logistic_loss/mul (defined at <ipython-input-61-06d6f3664a3f>:76) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_36488]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

The error says its the checkpoint argument on line 76 but I'm pretty sure it has to do with the train_generator argument on line 71, because the error doesn't change unless I modify that argument.

Changing the last Dense layer to 3 makes the error go away, since I'm pretty sure the 2 has to do with whether a mask is on or off, adding a third option messes that logic up in the later steps.

What I want to know is what exactly the [10,3] and [10,2] in the error is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the link given in the question, it seems that the project works on detecting if a person is wearing a mask or not. So it's a **binary** classification. So the output shape of the model should be `(10, 2)` where 10 is batch size and 3 the number of classes.

As you can see in the ouptut of the code, the train and test generators say that they found `3` classes. So the generators generates tensors of shape (10,3) where 10 is batch size and 3 the number of classes.

```
Found 1315 images belonging to 3 classes.
Found 194 images belonging to 3 classes.
```

So this is from where the error comes from.

As a solution, I suggest to check if these directories `./train` and `./test` contain only **TWO** files each, each one corresponding to a class.

```
--train
    -----mask
    -----no mask
--test
    -----mask
    -----no mask
```